# Why can't I join two Fire Offices together?

Tags: simcity-2013

I was setting up a Fire Station in the city, I have added some stuff in there, and I press Fire Office.  If I attempt to add a Fire Office adjacent to another one, so as to make a single and larger building, it won't go there.  The UI gives me no warnings saying I can't place it there.

Would you help me please?

Comment: Do you happen to have some screenshots of what is going on? It's kind of hard to visualize what your problem is right now.

Comment: @Ramirez I only have a video 10 seconds ago, it's quite fast but i'm making it slower.

Comment: I would post as an answer but I am not 100% sure on if this is correct or not. But based on your video you posted I feel like the tiny trash bin on the side of the previously existing building is the problem. I think the game is trying to put the building in the spot right next to the building and won't allow it because the building extends over the rectangular space just a bit because of the bin on the side. Again I'm not 100% sure but the video seems to show that.

Comment: @Ramirez Normally, I joined the second Fire Office to the first Fire Office and it will allow that.

Comment: Ok please, I really need answers that is my unanswered questions...

Comment: @Ramirez  It looks like that dumpster is just decor on the model, and not part of its footprint.

Answer (score 1):

is the terrain level? As while there may be space for it to plop, it may not be able to level the terrain. Try removing one that you've had to space apart, then re-plop it right next to it

Is the road perfectly straight?

In the video you plop 3 down, but don't attempt to plop the 3rd right next to the 2nd. Could you plop the 2nd next to the 3rd? Could the specific position between the 1st and 2nd be the issue?

Comment: +1. The footprints of buildings in SC13 are wack. OP can't place it because (it's obviously overlapping) their roads are wack, leaving the terrain still wack, making the UI not understand that round pegs don't go in square holes. I'd bet money that with perfectly level terrain and square roads, the UI wouldn't say, "Sure go ahead... Nope."